# Conversion Example of Stored Procedure Cursor within a Cursor for MySQL and MariaDB from Advantage

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, cursor, advantage-database-server

I am migrating from Advantage Database Server 11 to MySQL 8.0.33 and also testing MariaDB 11.0.2. I haven't landed on which one to use yet but I know I will need to use cursor variables and cursors within cursors a lot. I believe MariaDB has that feature. I successfully converted the SQL for MySQL/MariaDB so the procedure will finally create and run, but it does not complete or return results.

Here is the original Advantage SQL that runs correctly and returns results:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AllItemIDBom
   ( 
      RootItemID Integer OUTPUT,
      SortChar CHAR ( 44 ) OUTPUT,
      LevelID Integer OUTPUT,
      ParentItemID Integer OUTPUT,
      Seq Integer OUTPUT,
      Line Integer OUTPUT,
      ItemID Integer OUTPUT,
      LevelQty DOUBLE ( 2 ) OUTPUT,
      LevelWastePC DOUBLE ( 2 ) OUTPUT,
      RollDownQty DOUBLE ( 2 ) OUTPUT,
      OptionStdCost LOGICAL OUTPUT
   ) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE SOItems CURSOR;
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR;
DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR;
DECLARE cursor3 CURSOR;
// return variables  
DECLARE cycleID Integer;
DECLARE @tempSort Char(40);
DECLARE setNodeID1 Integer;

// select the group of Items
OPEN SOItems AS select ItemID from Item where ItemMfgTypeID >1;

WHILE FETCH SOItems DO
setNodeID1 =1000;
// set top level record as a place holder
  insert into __OUTPUT (RootItemID,SortChar, LevelID, ParentItemID, Seq, Line, ItemID, LevelQty, LevelWastePC, RollDownQty,OptionStdCost) 
    values (SOItems.ItemID,'0',0,SOItems.ItemID,0,0,SOItems.ItemID,1,0,1,TRUE);
// first pass go to the ItemMtl
  OPEN cursor1 AS SELECT ItemMtl.* FROM ItemMtl 
        where ItemMtl.ItemID=SOItems.ItemID
        and (EffectDate IS NULL OR EffectDate <= curdate())  
            and (ExpireDate IS NULL OR curdate() < ExpireDate)
        ORDER BY LINE ;

  WHILE FETCH cursor1 DO
    setNodeID1 =setNodeID1 +1;
    insert into __OUTPUT (RootItemID, SortChar, LevelID, ParentItemID, Seq, Line, ItemID, LevelQty, LevelWastePC, RollDownQty,OptionStdCost) 
      values (SOItems.ItemID, cast (setNodeID1 as SQL_CHAR) ,1, cursor1.ItemID,   
        cursor1.Seq, cursor1.Line, cursor1.MaterialItemID,  cursor1.UtopianQty, 
        ifNull(cursor1.WastePC,0),Round(Cursor1.UtopianQty /(1-IFNULL(Cursor1.WastePC,0)/100),4),cursor1.OptionStdCost);   
      
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE cursor1;

  cycleID = 1;
  // loop through
  WHILE cycleID < 10 DO
    OPEN cursor2 AS SELECT * FROM __OUTPUT  where  LevelID=cycleID and RootItemID =SOItems.ItemID;
    WHILE FETCH cursor2 DO    
      OPEN cursor3 AS SELECT ItemMtl.*
        FROM ItemMtl 
          where ItemMtl.ItemID=cursor2.ItemID 
              and (EffectDate IS NULL OR EffectDate <= curdate())  
                and (ExpireDate IS NULL OR curdate() < ExpireDate)
      ORDER BY LINE;
        setNodeID1 = 2000;          
      WHILE FETCH cursor3 DO
          setNodeID1 =setNodeID1 +1;      
            @tempSort =  RTRIM(cursor2.SortChar) + RTRIM(cast(setNodeID1 as SQL_CHAR));      
        insert into __OUTPUT  (RootItemID, SortChar, LevelID, ParentItemID, Seq, Line, ItemID, LevelQty, LevelWastePC, RollDownQty,OptionStdCost)   
        values (SOItems.ItemID, @tempSort, cycleID+1, cursor3.ItemID, 
             cursor3.Seq, cursor3.Line, cursor3.MaterialItemID, ifnull(cursor3.UtopianQty,0), ifnull(cursor3.WastePC,0),
            Round(Cursor3.UtopianQty /(1-IFNULL(Cursor3.WastePC,0)/100) * cursor2.RollDownQty,4), cursor3.OptionStdCost );
      END WHILE;  
      CLOSE cursor3;
      
    END WHILE;    
    CLOSE cursor2;
    cycleID = cycleID +1;
  END WHILE;
END WHILE;
CLOSE SOItems;
```

And here is the converted procedure I am testing in MySQL 8.0.33 and MariaDB 11.0.2. It doesn't complete or return results so something isn't right. I'm used to declaring the cursor, setting it later, then accessing and using its results in another cursor, so I had to move things around a bit to convert it. Advantage could also return entire result sets so had to use temp table in this version.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE AllItemIDBom()
BEGIN                  
-- return variables  
DECLARE cycleID Integer;
DECLARE tempSort Char(40);
DECLARE setNodeID1 Integer;
-- cursor variables
DECLARE SOItems_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_Seq Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_Line Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_MaterialItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_UtopianQty DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor1_WastePC VARCHAR(200); 
DECLARE cursor1_OptionStdCost BOOLEAN; 
DECLARE cursor2_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor2_SortChar Integer; 
DECLARE cursor2_RollDownQty DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor3_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_Seq Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_Line Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_MaterialItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_UtopianQty DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor3_WastePC DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor3_OptionStdCost BOOLEAN;      
-- setup cursor and handler
DECLARE SOItemsDone Integer DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE SOItems CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID FROM Item WHERE ItemMfgTypeID >1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET SOItemsDone = 1;  
    
-- prepare processing table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_AllItemIDBom;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_AllItemIDBom
   (
      RootItemID Integer,
      SortChar CHAR (44),
      LevelID Integer,
      ParentItemID Integer,
      Seq Integer,
      Line Integer,
      ItemID Integer,
      LevelQty DOUBLE,
      LevelWastePC DOUBLE,
      RollDownQty DOUBLE,
      OptionStdCost CHAR(1)
   );

-- select the group of Items
OPEN SOItems;
loop1: REPEAT   
      FETCH SOItems INTO SOItems_ItemID;
      SET setNodeID1 = 1000;
      -- set top level record as a place holder
      INSERT INTO temp_AllItemIDBom (RootItemID,SortChar,LevelID,ParentItemID,Seq,Line,ItemID,LevelQty,LevelWastePC,RollDownQty,OptionStdCost) 
            VALUES (SOItems_ItemID,'0',0,SOItems_ItemID,0,0,SOItems_ItemID,1,0,1,TRUE);

      -- first pass go to the ItemMtl
      BEGIN
            -- setup cursor and handler
            DECLARE Cur1Done Integer DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID,Seq,Line,MaterialItemID,UtopianQty,WastePC,OptionStdCost FROM ItemMtl WHERE ItemMtl.ItemID=SOItems_ItemID
                                                      AND (EffectDate IS NULL OR EffectDate <= curdate())  
                                                       AND (ExpireDate IS NULL OR curdate() < ExpireDate)
                                                      ORDER BY LINE;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Cur1Done = 1;  
            
            OPEN cursor1;
            loop2: REPEAT
                  FETCH cursor1 INTO cursor1_ItemID,cursor1_Seq,cursor1_Line,cursor1_MaterialItemID,cursor1_UtopianQty,cursor1_WastePC,cursor1_OptionStdCost;    
                  SET setNodeID1 =setNodeID1 +1;
                  INSERT INTO temp_AllItemIDBom (RootItemID,SortChar,LevelID,ParentItemID,Seq,Line,ItemID,LevelQty,LevelWastePC,RollDownQty,OptionStdCost) 
                        VALUES (SOItems_ItemID, cast(setNodeID1 as CHAR) ,1, cursor1_ItemID,   
                              cursor1_Seq, cursor1_Line, cursor1_MaterialItemID, cursor1_UtopianQty, 
                              ifNull(cursor1_WastePC,0),Round(Cursor1_UtopianQty /(1-IFNULL(Cursor1_WastePC,0)/100),4),cursor1_OptionStdCost); 
            UNTIL Cur1Done END REPEAT loop2;
            CLOSE cursor1;
      END;

      SET cycleID = 1;
      -- loop through children
      loop3: WHILE cycleID < 10 DO
            BEGIN
                  -- setup cursor and handler
                  DECLARE Cur2Done Integer DEFAULT 0;
                  DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID,SortChar,RollDownQty FROM temp_AllItemIDBom WHERE LevelID=cycleID AND RootItemID=SOItems_ItemID;
                  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Cur2Done = 1; 
                  OPEN cursor2;
                  loop4: REPEAT  
                        BEGIN
                              DECLARE Cur3Done Integer DEFAULT 0;
                              DECLARE cursor3 CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID,Seq,Line,MaterialItemID,UtopianQty,WastePC,OptionStdCost FROM ItemMtl WHERE ItemMtl.ItemID=cursor2_ItemID 
                                                                                                             AND (EffectDate IS NULL OR EffectDate <= curdate())  
                                                                                                             AND (ExpireDate IS NULL OR curdate() < ExpireDate)
                                                                                                            ORDER BY LINE;      
                              DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Cur3Done = 1; 
                              FETCH cursor2 INTO cursor2_ItemID,cursor2_SortChar,cursor2_RollDownQty; 
                              OPEN cursor3;
                              SET setNodeID1 = 2000;  
                              loop5: REPEAT
                                    FETCH cursor3 INTO cursor3_ItemID,cursor3_Seq,cursor3_Line,cursor3_MaterialItemID,cursor3_UtopianQty,cursor3_WastePC,cursor3_OptionStdCost;
                                    SET setNodeID1 =setNodeID1 +1;      
                                    SET tempSort = RTRIM(cursor2_SortChar) + RTRIM(cast(setNodeID1 as CHAR));      
                                    INSERT INTO temp_AllItemIDBom  (RootItemID, SortChar, LevelID, ParentItemID, Seq, Line, ItemID, LevelQty, LevelWastePC, RollDownQty,OptionStdCost)   
                                    VALUES (SOItems_ItemID, tempSort, cycleID+1, cursor3_ItemID, 
                                                 cursor3_Seq, cursor3_Line, cursor3_MaterialItemID, ifnull(cursor3_UtopianQty,0), ifnull(cursor3_WastePC,0),
                                                Round(Cursor3_UtopianQty /(1-IFNULL(Cursor3_WastePC,0)/100) * cursor2_RollDownQty,4), cursor3_OptionStdCost );
                              UNTIL Cur3Done END REPEAT loop5;
                              CLOSE cursor3;   
                        END;  
                  UNTIL Cur2Done END REPEAT loop4;    
                  CLOSE cursor2;
                  SET cycleID = cycleID +1;  
            END;
      END WHILE loop3;
UNTIL SOItemsDone END REPEAT loop1;
CLOSE SOItems;

SELECT * FROM temp_AllItemIDBom;

END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Example Usage: ItemNo 1016-FR is ItemID 10004, a 16" BMX Bike Frame with a bill of material of four components.

[image]

The procedure gets the top level and all it's children, and their children, through all indented levels, outputting the below results by level (though in this particular example there is only a single level).

[image]

Here is a script to setup a small database with sample data for testing the procedure.

```
CREATE DATABASE TestProc;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TestProc.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
USE TestProc;
CREATE TABLE Item ( 
  ItemID Integer,
  ItemMfgTypeID Integer);
INSERT INTO Item (ItemID,ItemMfgTypeID)
VALUES (10004,2),
       (10001,1),
       (10008,1),
       (10009,1),
       (10010,1);
CREATE TABLE ItemMtl (
  ItemID Integer,
  Seq Integer,
  Line Integer,
  MaterialItemID Integer,
  UtopianQty Double,
  WastePC Double,
  OptionStdCost Boolean,
  EffectDate Date,
  ExpireDate Date);
INSERT INTO ItemMtl (ItemID,Seq,Line,MaterialItemID,UtopianQty,WastePC,OptionStdCost,EffectDate,ExpireDate)
VALUES (10004,1,10,10001,6,0,True,NULL,NULL),
       (10004,2,20,10008,5.5,0,True,NULL,NULL),
       (10004,3,30,10009,0.35,0,True,NULL,NULL),
       (10004,4,40,10010,0.25,0,True,NULL,NULL);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: And you may want to know that MariaDB and MySQL are different products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have been changing gradually since then, with little or no attention to keeping them compatible. You should not think of MariaDB as "a type of MySQL" at all now.

Comment: I don't quite understand the logic of your procedure, but it looks like you're trying to query a recursive collection, like a classic parts explosion problem. Are you aware that MySQL 8 supports recursive queries? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive It could dramatically simplify your code.

Comment: If you were show the table definitions (please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) and a few rows of sample data, and then show an example of the result you want, that would help. Either I or someone else could suggest a simpler solution.

Comment: @BillKarwin - Looks like MariaDB executed and created the procedure using the very same SQL just fine, it was the explain throwing me errors, I just needed to go ahead and execute it. So, I edited to remove that portion of the issue, I was mistaken. I will look into recursive examples, thank you, sir. I'll see if I can put together an example structure and image of results to aid in figuring this out.

Comment: @BillKarwin - I have added an example usage with images, hope that helps!

Comment: @Daniel no, showing sample data and expected results as images don't help! Please post the tables as create table statements, sample data as insert statements, expected and actual results as text tables.

Comment: There are numerous [good reasons to avoid posting images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) of code or data on Stack Overflow. The primary reason in this case is that if you only posting images, any people who want to test solutions before they post an answer are forced to manually type in the table and the data by looking at your image. They might decide this is too much work, and they'll decide not to post a solution to help you. If you want good responses, _help us to help you_ — provide a ready example we can copy & paste.

Comment: @BillKarwin, I thought you might see something obvious from looking at the SQL, sorry, I didn't realize a test environment was necessary, but I can certainly see how it would help. I didn't post any images of code, only example of bill-of-material relationship and output, which you don't need to type. All code was pasted as text you can copy. I will work on statements for test environment your side and sample record, tomorrow. 

Comment: I did look at the SQL, and I commented that I thought it could be rewritten as a recursive query. You shared the procedure but not the table definitions that the procedure queries. I don't like to post solutions unless I have tested them, with as close to the accurate model of the tables and data as possible. If I guess at the tables, then there are likely to be discrepancies so my solution isn't usable by the person who asked the question, and we will both have wasted our time.

Comment: Also please be specific about which version of MySQL you are using. Run the query `SELECT VERSION();` to find out. Sometimes the best solution relies on SQL features in the most recent release of the product.

Comment: @BillKarwin, good stuff, will do, can't believe I forgot the version info. I have now added that and a script to setup the test data (minimal, just what's needed for the procedure). Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and thought I would share the answer. This one produces the desired results/output. Though I will probably end up rewriting the procedure as a recursive CTE based something akin to Bill's recommendation, this one keeps it as a stored procedure and truly rewrites it, converted from Advantage to MySQL 8.0.33 / MariaDB 11.0.2. Part of our desire for it as a procedure is to avoid any embedding of SQL in our app, keeping it all in the database.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE AllItemIDBom()
BEGIN                  
-- return variables  
DECLARE cycleID Integer;
DECLARE tempSort Char(40);
DECLARE setNodeID1 Integer;
-- cursor variables
DECLARE SOItems_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_Seq Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_Line Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_MaterialItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor1_UtopianQty DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor1_WastePC VARCHAR(200); 
DECLARE cursor1_OptionStdCost BOOLEAN; 
DECLARE cursor2_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor2_SortChar VARCHAR(16383); 
DECLARE cursor2_RollDownQty DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor3_ItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_Seq Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_Line Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_MaterialItemID Integer; 
DECLARE cursor3_UtopianQty DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor3_WastePC DOUBLE; 
DECLARE cursor3_OptionStdCost BOOLEAN;      
-- setup handler toggles
DECLARE SOItemsDone Integer DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE Cur1Done Integer;
DECLARE Cur2Done Integer;
DECLARE Cur3Done Integer;
-- setup 1st cursor and handler
DECLARE SOItems CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID FROM Item WHERE ItemMfgTypeID IN (2,3,4) AND suspended = false AND MRPInclude= true;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET SOItemsDone = 1;  
    
-- prepare processing table
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_AllItemIDBom;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_AllItemIDBom
   (
      RootItemID Integer,
      SortChar CHAR (44),
      LevelID Integer,
      ParentItemID Integer,
      Seq Integer,
      Line Integer,
      ItemID Integer,
      LevelQty DOUBLE,
      LevelWastePC DOUBLE,
      RollDownQty DOUBLE,
      OptionStdCost CHAR(1)
   );

-- select the group of Items
SET SOItemsDone = 0;
OPEN SOItems;
BLOCK1: REPEAT   
  SET Cur1Done = 0;
  FETCH SOItems INTO SOItems_ItemID;      
  IF NOT SOItemsDone THEN 
    SET setNodeID1 = 1000;
    -- set top level record as a place holder
    INSERT INTO temp_AllItemIDBom (RootItemID,SortChar,LevelID,ParentItemID,Seq,Line,ItemID,LevelQty,LevelWastePC,RollDownQty,OptionStdCost) 
          VALUES (SOItems_ItemID,'0',0,SOItems_ItemID,0,0,SOItems_ItemID,1,0,1,TRUE);

    -- first pass go to the ItemMtl
    BEGIN
      -- setup 2nd cursor and handler
      DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID,Seq,Line,MaterialItemID,UtopianQty,WastePC,OptionStdCost FROM ItemMtl WHERE ItemMtl.ItemID=SOItems_ItemID
                                 AND (EffectDate IS NULL OR EffectDate <= curdate())  
                                 AND (ExpireDate IS NULL OR curdate() < ExpireDate)
                                 ORDER BY LINE;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Cur1Done = 1;  
      
      OPEN cursor1;
      BLOCK2: REPEAT
        FETCH cursor1 INTO cursor1_ItemID,cursor1_Seq,cursor1_Line,cursor1_MaterialItemID,cursor1_UtopianQty,cursor1_WastePC,cursor1_OptionStdCost;    
        IF NOT Cur1Done THEN 
          SET setNodeID1 = setNodeID1 + 1;
          INSERT INTO temp_AllItemIDBom (RootItemID,SortChar,LevelID,ParentItemID,Seq,Line,ItemID,LevelQty,LevelWastePC,RollDownQty,OptionStdCost) 
            VALUES (SOItems_ItemID, cast(setNodeID1 as CHAR) ,1, cursor1_ItemID,cursor1_Seq, cursor1_Line, cursor1_MaterialItemID, cursor1_UtopianQty, 
                  ifNull(cursor1_WastePC,0),Round(Cursor1_UtopianQty /(1-IFNULL(Cursor1_WastePC,0)/100),4),cursor1_OptionStdCost); 
        END IF;
      UNTIL Cur1Done END REPEAT BLOCK2;
      CLOSE cursor1;
    END;

    SET cycleID = 1;
    -- loop through children
    BLOCK3: WHILE cycleID < 10 DO
      SET Cur2Done = 0;
      BEGIN
        -- setup 3rd cursor and handler
        DECLARE cursor2 CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID,SortChar,RollDownQty FROM temp_AllItemIDBom WHERE LevelID=cycleID AND RootItemID=SOItems_ItemID;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Cur2Done = 1; 
        OPEN cursor2;
        BLOCK4: REPEAT 
          SET Cur3Done = 0;
          FETCH cursor2 INTO cursor2_ItemID,cursor2_SortChar,cursor2_RollDownQty; 
          IF NOT Cur2Done THEN 
            BEGIN
              -- setup cursor and handler
              DECLARE cursor3 CURSOR FOR SELECT ItemID,Seq,Line,MaterialItemID,UtopianQty,WastePC,OptionStdCost FROM ItemMtl WHERE ItemMtl.ItemID=cursor2_ItemID 
                                         AND (EffectDate IS NULL OR EffectDate <= curdate())  
                                         AND (ExpireDate IS NULL OR curdate() < ExpireDate)
                                         ORDER BY LINE;      
              DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET Cur3Done = 1; 
              OPEN cursor3;
              SET setNodeID1 = 2000;  
              BLOCK5: REPEAT
                FETCH cursor3 INTO cursor3_ItemID,cursor3_Seq,cursor3_Line,cursor3_MaterialItemID,cursor3_UtopianQty,cursor3_WastePC,cursor3_OptionStdCost;
                IF NOT Cur3Done THEN
                  SET setNodeID1 = setNodeID1 + 1;      
                  SET tempSort = CONCAT(RTRIM(cursor2_SortChar),RTRIM(cast(setNodeID1 as CHAR)));
                  INSERT INTO temp_AllItemIDBom (RootItemID,SortChar,LevelID,ParentItemID,Seq,Line,ItemID,LevelQty,LevelWastePC,RollDownQty,OptionStdCost)   
                  VALUES (SOItems_ItemID,tempSort,cycleID+1,cursor3_ItemID,cursor3_Seq,cursor3_Line,cursor3_MaterialItemID,ifnull(cursor3_UtopianQty,0),ifnull(cursor3_WastePC,0),
                    Round(Cursor3_UtopianQty /(1-IFNULL(Cursor3_WastePC,0)/100) * cursor2_RollDownQty,4),cursor3_OptionStdCost);
                END IF;
              UNTIL Cur3Done END REPEAT BLOCK5;
              CLOSE cursor3;   
            END;  
          END IF;
        UNTIL Cur2Done END REPEAT BLOCK4;    
        CLOSE cursor2;
        SET cycleID = cycleID +1;  
      END;
    END WHILE BLOCK3;
  END IF;
UNTIL SOItemsDone END REPEAT BLOCK1;
CLOSE SOItems;

SELECT * FROM temp_AllItemIDBom ORDER BY RootItemID,SortChar;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

As it turns out, to prevent the infinite looping issue, I (a) added "IF NOT done THEN" type of statements to each block and (b) moved all fetch statements to just before those IF statements.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for providing a test case. I tested your procedure. It results in an infinite loop due to the logic. Frankly, I can't believe that your original procedure for Advantage SQL worked, because it appears to have the same logic problem.

Basically, as I read it, you're inserting `ItemID` into the temp table where you should be inserting `MaterialItemID`. So every item becomes its own parent, and you loop forever.

Here's a solution using a recursive common table expression:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT Item.ItemID AS RootItemID,
    0 AS LevelID,
    Item.ItemID AS ParentItemID,
    0 AS Seq,
    0 AS Line,
    ItemID AS ItemID,
    CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS LevelQty,
    0 AS LevelWastePC,
    CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS RollDownQty,
    True AS OptionStdCost
  FROM Item
  WHERE ItemMfgTypeID > 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cte.RootItemID,
    cte.LevelID + 1,
    cte.ItemID,
    l.Seq,
    l.Line,
    l.MaterialItemID,
    l.UtopianQty,
    l.WastePC,
    l.UtopianQty,
    l.OptionStdCost
  FROM ItemMtl AS l JOIN cte USING (ItemID)
  WHERE (EffectDate IS NULL OR EffectDate <= curdate())
    AND (ExpireDate IS NULL OR curdate() < ExpireDate)
)
SELECT RootItemID,
  CAST(1000*LevelID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LevelID ORDER BY Line) AS CHAR(44)) AS SortChar,
  LevelID,
  ParentItemID,
  Seq,
  Line,
  ItemID,
  LevelQty,
  LevelWastePC,
  RollDownQty,
  OptionStdCost
FROM cte;
```

Output given your sample data:

```
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| RootItemID | SortChar | LevelID | ParentItemID | Seq  | Line | ItemID | LevelQty | LevelWastePC | RollDownQty | OptionStdCost |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|      10004 | 1        |       0 |        10004 |    0 |    0 |  10004 |     1.00 |            0 |        1.00 |             1 |
|      10004 | 1001     |       1 |        10004 |    1 |   10 |  10001 |     6.00 |            0 |        6.00 |             1 |
|      10004 | 1002     |       1 |        10004 |    2 |   20 |  10008 |     5.50 |            0 |        5.50 |             1 |
|      10004 | 1003     |       1 |        10004 |    3 |   30 |  10009 |     0.35 |            0 |        0.35 |             1 |
|      10004 | 1004     |       1 |        10004 |    4 |   40 |  10010 |     0.25 |            0 |        0.25 |             1 |
+------------+----------+---------+--------------+------+------+--------+----------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

Dbfiddle to demonstrate working test on MySQL 8.0: https://dbfiddle.uk/C_WPR7DI

This query doesn't have to be in a stored procedure. You can execute the query directly from client code.

To be honest, MySQL stored procedures are not my favorite. They have poor performance, they have no feature of packages, or a debugger, or a compiler. There's no standard library of stored procedures. The documentation is pretty much only reference documentation, without a good tutorial or task-oriented docs, so it's hard to learn. I don't use stored procedures in MySQL myself, and I don't recommend them.

Comment: This solution worked great. Thank you, Bill! I think the original procedure worked because (a) it only inserts the ItemID on the first pass for the parent level, then moves on to the children--so I must not have converted it properly--and (b) it's a bit confusing but the MaterialItemID is also the ItemID in the parent table, so it is drilling down into it's own children's bill-of-materials. It would only be an infinite loop if you put a parent somewhere in it's descendants BOM. I must have screwed up the conversion. At any rate, your solution is elegant, I like it! 

Comment: Do you prefer MariaDB over MySQL? We like the idea that they are open source and work well with Delphi, the language of our app. We are doing proof-of-concept and exploring our options before migrating and overhauling all our code. We welcome any thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I don't use MariaDB. Technically, I have no problem with them. I'm sure they've done good work. But I don't like the misleading marketing they have done. For example, claiming that they are somehow "more open source" than MySQL. MySQL has the same license they've always had — GPL with optional Enterprise license. MariaDB uses the same license.

Comment: Now that I'm starting to compare results back in production database, I am finding a few issues. There are fewer records in the recursive CTE so some levels or records are missing though I haven't found the exact pattern yet, the SortChar isn't following the right numerical pattern, roll down qty isn't quite rounded right. I can't paste an image in this comment else I'd show you a comparison of output results between the two. I will investigate further and circle back. The first SortChar should be 0, then level 1 is 1001, level 2 is 10012001, and so forth.

Comment: I couldn't tell exactly how to format the SortChar from your minimal sample data. So you can use the query I showed as a demonstration of the technique of using a recursive CTE query. I'll leave it to you to refine it to produce the result you want.

Comment: Understood. Well I appreciate you teaching me about recursive CTE's. Though I'm sure that my final solution will be a modified form of that, I would still like to figure out and fix the original procedure just so I understand MySQL better and what my problem was, so I will continue to play with both. If you have any other suggestions on the original or if anything looks wrong with that, let me know. Thanks, Bill!

Comment: BTW, I purchased a copy of your book, looks pretty cool. I'm always looking to learn. Not sure if there is a difference in the one titled "Volume 1" or not. I got the same title but doesn't have "Volume 1" in it like the other one does, is just SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming. Look forward to it.

Comment: @Daniel, the one with "Volume 1" is a second edition, I published in 2022, with updates and some new content. I'm currently working on Volume 2, which will be all new content. In hindsight I should have given the revision the same title as the original plus "Second Edition," because Amazon treats the 2022 edition as a completely different book. I don't get to associate the new release with the ratings and reviews from the earlier edition. Lesson learned. :-(

Comment: @Daniel, Here are more details about the differences: https://www.quora.com/What-is-new-in-the-book-SQL-Antipatterns-Volume-1-compared-to-the-2010-version/answer/Bill-Karwin

Comment: Oh wow, wish I'd chosen the newer one, LOL! Maybe down the road. Thanks!

Comment: I figured out that in my converted procedure, my REPEAT statements are looping too many times. If I comment out all the inner cursors leaving only the first outer cursor, it still returns two identical rows instead of just one, so I think it might be my repeat loops that are causing the issue. They look right to me, though. What am I doing wrong? I set SOItemsDone default 0, setup handler and set to 1 when not found/EOF, repeat until SOItemsDone. How is it returning two rows when there is only one ItemID to fetch? I'm used to "WHILE FETCH" and no checking for EOF.